# Perverse sheaves and representation theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, perverse-sheaves, geometric-representation-theory

At my university we are having a working group on perverse sheaves, with the aim of applying them to representation theory (Lusztig canonical bases for quivers/quantum groups etc). We are still lacking the idea of why we should be "naturally"interested in this.  How would you motivate the appearance of these objects in representation theory and why one should be interested in this?

Another question would be maybe the historical developement of these ideas inside geometric representation theory.

Comment: I recommend Kleiman's article "The Development of Intersection Homology Theory" (PAMQ 2007), section 4.

Comment: It's better to have one question per question.  Your second question is better suited for [HSMSE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I often find geometric constructions of representation theoretic objects more natural than purely algebraic constructions, but maybe that’s just me

Comment: @leibnewtz I often find algebraic constructions of representation theoretic objects more natural than purely geometric constructions, but maybe that’s just me :)